# Magento: How to change the pagination url ?p=1 to ?page=1 in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I have created a custom module, for pagination added this block:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(3=>3,6=>6,9=>9,'all'=>'all'));
    $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

Added following in template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

My pagination url's work as:
http://test.com/test-landing.html?p=2

But instead of "p" I want to use "page" like this way
http://test.com/test-landing.html?page=2

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to override Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager like below:

create etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager">
        <plugin name="name-your-plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PagerPlugin" sortOrder="5" />
    </type>
</config>
```

create PagerPlugin.php under Vendor\Module\Plugin

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class PagerPlugin
{    

    public function afterGetPageVarName(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $subject, $result)
    {

        return "page";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I am using magento 1 not for magento 2

Comment: then override this file Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager and change protected $_pageVarName    = 'p'; to protected $_pageVarName    = 'page';

Comment: But I want it for the custom module only

Comment: override Mage_Page_Block_Html_Page and override below method:         
    public function getPageVarName()
    {  if(condition_for_your_module) {return "page";}else{
        return $this->_pageVarName; }
    }

Comment: Happy coding. :) If things work out, don't forget to upvote as it may help others also.